# how works with Linear ColorMap

Tags: python, folium

I have question to branca.colormap

Below code works:

```
from branca.colormap import linear
x=linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(1,10)
```

but I would like to use a different color palette for example gnuplot or gnuplot2

Below code doesn't work:

```
from branca.colormap import linear
x=linear.gnuplot.scale(1,10)
```

I have error '_LinearColormaps' object has not attribiute 'gnuplot'. Do You know how use other pallet with linearColormap or where can I find list of available colors names ?

I have one more question, below my code

```
import folium
import branca.colormap as cm
color_mapa=cm.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(1,10)
color_mapa=color_mapa.to_step(index=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
color_mapa2=color_mapa.to_linear()
m=folium.Map(location=[52,20],zoom_start=7)
color_mapa.add_to(m)
color_mapa.caption='Colors'
color_mapa.add_to(m)
color_mapa2.add_to(m)
color_mapa2.caption='Colors2'
color_mapa2.add_to(m)
m.save('mapy_test.html')
```

The problem is when I want add lables. I do this by 'to_step()' and define index. But then colors don't change smoothly. So I add 'to_linear()' (color_mapa2), but this change labels (Colors2 on my peacture). Is the way to keep labels and have colors change smoothly ?
[image]

Comment: The [branca documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/branca/) is a natural place to look.

Comment: neither YlOrRd works

Comment: do something like this instead

```from branca.colormap import LinearColormap

# Create a colormap instance
colormap = LinearColormap(colors=['red', 'green', 'blue'], vmin=0, vmax=1)

# Scale the colormap to the desired range
scaled_colormap = colormap.scale(1, 10)```

Comment: Hi, thanks - "neither YlOrRd works" - I have corrected the code.

Comment: See [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Colormaps.ipynb) for more information on the different types of colormaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`dir()` function** from the **Python standard library** to see all the **attributes** from the `linear` object :

```py
>>> dir(linear)

['Accent_03',
 'Accent_04',
 'Accent_05',
 'Accent_06',
 'Accent_07',
 'Accent_08',
 'Blues_03',
...]
```